# Drupal Add contextual filters in view

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-contextual-filters

We were trying to add field in contextual filters view .In local server its working but only in  Live domain PHP version 5.6.25 its not working(some fields are not added). 
Eg: Content: Course (field_accreditation_course)
Appears in: node:accreditation
Is there any other way to add a field to contextual filter.

Comment: We have fixed that issue the reason is we can't name the field and content type similar.  we have done earlier now its changed . Its working fine now.